# Hive 2 JDBC PreparedStatement throws an error cannot recognize input near '?' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in expression specification

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, prepared-statement

```
try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String query = "SELECT spd_field_label_id FROM RAL WHERE SUBJECT_USER_ID = ?";

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    boolean testCasePassed = false;

    try {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setString(1, "USR-44");
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        Assert.assertNotNull(resultSet);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            testCasePassed = true;
            System.out.println("=======Test =========" + resultSet.getString("spd_field_label_id"));
        }
    } finally {

        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }

        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }

    }

    return testCasePassed;
```

RAL is a simple Hive table with String type columns spd_field_label_id and SUBJECT_USER_ID.

Simple PreparedStatement using Hive2 throwing an Error stacktrace below. Any pointers on what could be wrong? Same query works fine when using Statement instead of PreparedStatement and without using ? for parameter binding.

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:62 cannot recognize input near '?' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in expression specification
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:264)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:250)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:309)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:250)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
```

Comment: Post the real code. At least the real query.

Comment: Hi EJP the query is real it is just trying to get a String column based on a where clause for a string column, I have pasted the actual code which I am trying to run in a Junit Test case. The query works fine when executed on Hive command line or through Statement without using ?

Comment: No, the query was ***not*** real. It was clearly made-up, with names like `someTableName`. That's why Iasked you to change it. Otherwise why *did* you change it? Don't talk nonsense here.

Comment: Please mind your language EJP, I am not here to fight with you! how does it matter the columnName is someColumnName or spd_field_label_id or table name is RAL? Does it make any difference especially when it's my specific table structure when I already mentioned it's a string column and I am querying for another string column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

You're using the wrong method. You've already prepared the statement. It is ready to execute. It should be:

```
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks EJP changing executeQuery to execute() makes it work

Comment: `stmt.execute();` is returning a boolean but I want the result set of that query, how can I do it? Simply run `stmt.executeQuery();` ?