# Java HivePreparedStatement example

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, prepared-statement

Can someone show an example java program of HivePreparedStatement that can be used to connect to hive tables and retrieve data from it.

https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HivePreparedStatement.html

I was trying with the following code and I am unable to complete it as there are many parameters for the constructor

```
      TCLIService.Iface client =null;
      EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService embeddedClient = new EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService();
      embeddedClient.init(null);
      client = embeddedClient;

      TOpenSessionReq openReq = new TOpenSessionReq();

      JdbcConnectionParams connParams = Utils.parseURL("jdbc:hive2://168.61.32.157:10000/nadb");

      Map<String, String> openConf = new HashMap<String, String>();
      // for remote JDBC client, try to set the conf var using 'set foo=bar'
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> hiveConf : connParams.getHiveConfs().entrySet()) {
        openConf.put("set:hiveconf:" + hiveConf.getKey(), hiveConf.getValue());
      }
      // For remote JDBC client, try to set the hive var using 'set hivevar:key=value'
      for (Map.Entry<String, String=> hiveVar : connParams.getHiveVars().entrySet()) {
        openConf.put("set:hivevar:" + hiveVar.getKey(), hiveVar.getValue());
      }
      // switch the database
      openConf.put("use:database", connParams.getDbName());
      // set the fetchSize
      openConf.put("set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size",
        Integer.toString(fetchSize));

      // set the session configuration
      Map<String, String> sessVars = connParams.getSessionVars();
      if (sessVars.containsKey(HiveAuthFactory.HS2_PROXY_USER)) {
        openConf.put(HiveAuthFactory.HS2_PROXY_USER,
            sessVars.get(HiveAuthFactory.HS2_PROXY_USER));
      }
      openReq.setConfiguration(openConf);

      // Store the user name in the open request in case no non-sasl authentication
      if (JdbcConnectionParams.AUTH_SIMPLE.equals(sessConfMap.get(JdbcConnectionParams.AUTH_TYPE))) {
        openReq.setUsername(sessConfMap.get(JdbcConnectionParams.AUTH_USER));
        openReq.setPassword(sessConfMap.get(JdbcConnectionParams.AUTH_PASSWD));
      }

      TOpenSessionResp openResp = client.OpenSession(openReq);

      // validate connection
      Utils.verifySuccess(openResp.getStatus());
      if (!supportedProtocols.contains(openResp.getServerProtocolVersion())) {
        throw new TException("Unsupported Hive2 protocol");
      }
      protocol = openResp.getServerProtocolVersion();
      sessHandle = openResp.getSessionHandle();


      HivePreparedStatement hivePreparedStatement = new HivePreparedStatement(con, client, sessHandle, sql);
```

Is there any simple method for doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Looked at the unit tests? https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/test/org/apache/hive/jdbc/TestHivePreparedStatement.java

Comment: I have updated the the question and thanks for the link but I couldn't understand where I can add the connection parameters for the hive jdbc driver along with username and password. In the Junit they just have mocked the connections and other parameters of the constructor

Comment: You should not instantiate `HivePreparedStatement` yourself, you should use `Connection.prepareStatement(...)`. This is the same for all JDBC drivers. Check any decent tutorial on JDBC. However the rest of your code seems to suggest that you are not even using the Hive JDBC driver, but instead messing around with a lower level protocol implementation. You likely can't use `HivePreparedStatement` that way (or at least not easily). (posting as a comment, as I don't have Hive specific knowledge)

Comment: Connection.preparestatement returns the object of PreparedStatement and not HivePreparedStatement. I tried to insert data into hive tables using jdbc prepared statement then I was getting an java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported. What can be done here?

Comment: Should work according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859270/hive-2-jdbc-preparedstatement-throws-an-error-cannot-recognize-input-near

Comment: `Connection.prepareStatement` returns `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, because that is how JDBC works: you use the JDBC API interface classes instead of specific implementation classes. If you then really need `HivePreparedStatement` you can unwrap or cast it (but really, you normally should not need to do that).